# Laying Out Buttons on iOS 5 for iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 or lower

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout, autosize

I'm having issues getting my screens to all look right in my app.  In the iPhone 3.5" screen it shows as:

[image]

This is great, however on a 4" screen it looks like:

[image]

The issue is that I CANNOT use autoLayout as I am building this to run on iOS 5.1 as the deployment target.  So, what are some ways that I can make the app buttons not cover up the logo on the iPhone 5 screen?

Comment: You'll have to dynamically select a background image at runtime based on the screen height. If you don't know how, there are dozens of questions here about it.

Comment: Take a look at UIScreen or self.view.bounds (if your subclassing a UIViewController class) and get the device height. then set the iamge based on the value

Comment: You can implement the same behavior (almost) of the AutoLayout, using Springs and Struts, from what I see your srpings and struts are not selected properly.